# Calling servlet from form isn't working

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

This is the code I'm using:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // whatever I need to do
    }
}
```

The `JSP`:

```
<form action="/myServlet" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myPackage.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This should work according to everything out there but clicking the submit button gives me a `HTTP Status 404` (for this url: `http://localhost:8080/myServlet`.) I restarted `tomcat` several times but it doesn't help. What am I missing?

EDIT: the `tomcat log`:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2015:17:31:55 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 951
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [21/Sep/2015:17:31:55 +0300] "GET /MyApp/ HTTP/1.1" 404 981
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [21/Sep/2015:17:32:16 +0300] "GET /MyApp/pages/appl.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 1024
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [21/Sep/2015:17:32:21 +0300] "POST /myServlet HTTP/1.1" 404 971
```

Comment: can you post the tomcat log?

Comment: Can you show here some log from tomcat?

Comment: and, where is the "myServlet.class" file located in the file system? paste the full path

Comment: It seems your context is missing. It should be `http://localhost:8080/yourapp/myServlet`

Comment: Yes, i think the conext is missing too... and the web.xml needs the <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

Comment: @DavidHerrero and the others, I edited the tomcat log into the question.

Answer (score 0):

If your project(app) is called 'myServlet', I think you should be hitting a url that looks like `http://localhost:8080/myServlet/myServlet` according to the way you have configured.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

http://localhost:8080/MyApp/myServlet

Seems that your App name is "MyApp"